# Batch file to read folders in a share and append each folder name to the end of a path

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to parallelise a script im using to backup some files using TSM.

Basically I run the following commands:

```
net use y: \\Server\share

dsmc incr y: -optfile="c:\path\folder\optionfile.opt" > c:\logs\logfile
```

.. and TSM backus up the entire directory tree in serial.

But I want to do this to create some seperate scripts to use more than one client to backup subsets of the directory tree (to speed things up)

```
FOR each subdirectory in \\Server\share

IF not processed 1/3 of the directories in \\server\share

DO



net use y: \\Server\share\**<append subdirectory here>**

Backup y
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
FOR /D %%a IN (W:) DO ( 

    net use y: \\server\share\%%a
    run command to backup y:
```

> (y:\ should be now \server\share\first_dir_name)

```
    net use y: /delete

    timeout /t 10
)
```

I still need the if logic to count the number of folders in the share.

The first step was to find how many top level sub directories are in the share:

I use `dir /a:d /s /b "Folder Path" | find /c ":\"` but the command never completes.

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks.

Comment: It appears that you've determined that you need a [tag:for-loop]. What I'd suggest therefore is that you use the search facility, _(at the top of each page)_, put together some code, run it, and if it fails to work as was written post a [mcve] of it together with the beginning and resulting result. Until you have done that, your question is an off topic code request, because you've not made a sufficient attempt at creating the required code yourself.

Comment: If you are backing up to a single device, then I doubt running multiple processes in parallel will give you a significant performance boost. The writes are probably already your bottleneck, so performing multiple writes in parallel is unlikely to improve things much.

Comment: No, ive performed multiple performance analysis using TSM's native tools, the write speed is not the bottleneck, in fact, there is no bottleneck.  The issue is you can only run a snappdiff backup from a NetApp SAN using TSM using one stream to a full volume, not a subtree.  But using multiple client requests would get around this.

Comment: about how many subdirectories are in \\Server\share?

Comment: about 100 subdirectories

Comment: `FOR /D %%a IN (Y:\*) DO ...`

Comment: Hi Stephan! Thanks for the correction.  Now I can see the subdirectories.  How do I pass the variable %%a into a function.  So for example if I say `FOR /D %%a IN (W:) DO net use W: \\server\share\%%a` .. it will map a drive for each subdirectory using the same letter.. but there are other commands I wish to run using the variable %a inside the loop before I want to reiterate over it.  Can you create a code block in batch scripting like this?  Thanks.

Comment: Of course, you can do code-blocks. See @RGuggisberg's answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using semaphore files.
In this example I have it set up for 8 separate tasks.
I recommend that you copy this code and test to see how it works and then change the number of scripts you want to run simultaneously or figure out the optimum number to run simultaneously and change the code to keep that number of scripts running until done. You didn't say how many separate scripts you will have.

**SeparateProcess.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Script[1]=Script1"
set "Script[2]=Script2"
set "Script[3]=Script3"
set "Script[4]=Script4"
set "Script[5]=Script5"
set "Script[6]=Script6"
set "Script[7]=Script7"
set "Script[8]=Script8"
set /a nScripts=8

rem For test only. Change values (seconds) below if desired
set /A testDelay[1]=10
set /A testDelay[2]=4
set /A testDelay[3]=8
set /A testDelay[4]=14
set /A testDelay[5]=17
set /A testDelay[6]=6
set /A testDelay[7]=9
set /A testDelay[8]=7

rem time to wait between checking status of all tasks
set /A timeout=5
set /A tasksProcessing=0

rem Set all Status to 0 and delete semaphore files.
for /L %%L in (1,1,%nScripts%) do set /A Status[%%L]=0 & del /f /q  "SemaphoreFile!Script[%%L].txt!" 2>nul

echo This program will simulate starting separate processes
echo Open a Windows Explorer to %CD% and observe that semaphore files appear.
echo Observe that the files disappear when the processes complete after varying  delays.
pause

echo Starting %nScripts% processes
for /L %%L in (1,1,%nScripts%) do (
   echo( >"SemaphoreFile!Script[%%L]!.txt"
   start /MIN cmd.exe /C !Script[%%L]!.bat "SemaphoreFile!Script[%%L]!.txt" !testDelay[%%L]!
   set /A Status[%%L]=1
   set /A tasksProcessing+=1
   )

:KeepChecking
for /L %%A in (1,1,%nScripts%) do (
   echo Waiting %timeout% seconds for !tasksProcessing! processes to complete
   timeout %timeout% >nul
   for /L %%L in (1,1,%nScripts%) do (
      if !Status[%%L]!==1 if not exist "SemaphoreFile!Script[%%L]!.txt" (
         set /A Status[%%L]=0
         set /A tasksProcessing-=1
         echo !Script[%%L]! finished.
         )
      )
   if !tasksProcessing! GTR 0 goto :KeepChecking
   goto :Done
   )

:done
echo All processes completed.
pause
endlocal
```

Then have 8 scripts that are identical (for this test) where n is 1-8.

**Scriptn.bat** (code below)

```
@echo off
REM 1=Filespec of semaphor file
REM 2=Delay in seconds. This is for test only.
echo %~nx1 is doing something
timeout %~2
del "%~1"
got :eof
```

Execute SeparateProcess.bat to see how it works. When you are satisfied with the results replace the code in Script1-8 with whatever you need them to do. Just make sure that the last thing they do is delete the semaphore file to indicate that they are done.

Comment: Hm, havent got a clue whats going on here to be honest, can you talk me through it?  I'm not sure how this solves the above question.

Comment: SeparateProcess.bat launches n number of separate processes (8 in this example). It writes a semaphore file for each process and then waits for the processes to complete... which they indicate by deleting the semaphore file. Make 8 copies of Scriptn and name them Scriptn(1-8).bat. Run SeparateProcess.bat and watch the processes complete. Of course you will replace Scriptn(1-8) with your scripts after you are satisfied that this is doing what you want.

Comment: I dont think this is doing what I need.  I dont want to write many scripts I need to write one script that reads the contents of the fileshare, then substitutes each folder name into the path of the TSM command. (as above)

Comment: SeparateProcess.bat is intended to be your engine. It will do what you want as far as running process simultaneously. Scriptn.bat is for test only. It is tested and will work. I can't test your code. It is up to you to do as you see fit by replacing Scriptn.bat with your Script(s), be they one or many.